# Error while converting string into integer in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and facing a problem while converting a string into an integer.
my coding goes here-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Binary{
public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner takeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Give Your Input ====> ");
    String binaryInput = takeInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your Input Is ====> "+binaryInput);
    int lenGTH=binaryInput.length();

    for(int i = lenGTH ; i >= 0 ; i--){

        char pOsition = binaryInput.charAt(i);
        int convertIntoInteger = Int.parseInt(pOsition);
        int convertIntoDouble = Double.parseDouble(convertIntoInteger);
        int getPower = 0;
        getPower *= Math.pow(convertIntoDouble , 2);
        System.out.println("Power of " + i + " index " + getPower);
        }

    }
}
```

---

I am giving the screenshot for error in command prompt:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQUK4.png)

Comment: Please add what's wrong, if there is an error.

Comment: If your code is indented properly, you are more likely to get people to try and read it.

Comment: `int i=lenGTH; i>=0; i--` - start at lenGTH - 1. Your String starts at index 0, and finishes at length-1. There is nothing worthwhile at index length. Also, this is a very unique casing you have there. Not saying CamelCase and snake_case are in danger, but nice anyway.

Comment: What error you are getting and at what line no.

Comment: `int convertIntoDouble=Double.parseDouble(convertIntoInteger);` ??? you are assigning `double` to `int`

Comment: Oh yeah. It should be also `Integer.parseInt`, not Int.parseInt

Comment: Also trying to parse a double from an integer, instead of from a string.

Comment: @Abhay  I have added a screenshot

Comment: @khelwood i think convert a string into double will give u just another error, because it may not be logically right to convert a string, say, "1" into "1.00"

Comment: It is perfectly valid to parse `1` into a double.

Comment: @skandigraun, it's not still working

Comment: And what's happening now?

Comment: showing in command prompt: binary.java:18: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
                        double convertIntoDouble=Double.parseDouble(pOsition);
                                                                     ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

Comment: Try it like `Double.parseDouble(binaryInput.substring(i, i+1))`. Maybe you will have to use `i-1` instead of one of the indices.

Comment: @skandigraun, it worked thanx.
valueOf()  method worked too... The one more problem was taking i = lenGTH, instead of lenGTH-1.
Thanks for your answer and i used valueOf() methd.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such class Int in java.

Try this:

```
int convertIntoInteger=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(p0sition));
```

Integer class is used to parse data in int.

Comment: i used valueOf() as Integer.valueOf() and it worked!
Thanks bro